# PHP - IMAP connection to Gmail returns nothing

Tags: php, email, imap

I am trying to connect to gmail using IMAP. When I try to load the script, the page just loads and and doesn't return anything. No error, no emails... it just tries loading.

I have IMAP enabled for PHP, and it's also enabled in my Gmail inbox.

```
    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
    $username = 'email@gmail.com';
    $password = 'password';
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
    imap_close($inbox);
```

Any ideas why the script won't stop loading?

Comment: Your not outputting anything, you are simply opening and then immediately closing the connection. Check out example 2 here http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firewall was blocking the port 993. Got it working. Thanks!